# Construction of $SU(2)_L$ invariant Lagrangian

Tags: field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, gauge-invariance

I am reading this paper about "[Scalar Electroweak Multiplet Dark Matter](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.07829.pdf)" written by Wei Chao et al. I am puzzled for their construction of $SU(2)_L$ invariant Lagrangian, Eq.(6).
$$
\begin{aligned}
V= & +M_A^2\left(\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi\right)+\left\{M_B^2(\Phi \Phi)_0+\text { h.c. }\right\}-\mu^2 H^{\dagger} H \\
& +\lambda\left(H^{\dagger} H\right)^2+\lambda_1\left(H^{\dagger} H\right)\left(\Phi^{\dagger} \Phi\right) \\
& +\lambda_2\left[(\overline{H} H)_1(\overline{\Phi} \Phi)_1\right]_0+\left[\lambda_3(\overline{H} H)_0(\Phi \Phi)_0+\text { h.c. }\right]
\end{aligned} \tag{6}
$$
where $H$ denotes the SM Higgs doublet, $\Phi$ denotes a new complex septuplet field. $\overline{H}$ and $\overline{\Phi}$ are complex conjugate representation of $H$ and $\Phi$. They show in Appendix A that $\overline{\Phi}$ and $\Phi$ transform in the same way under $SU(2)_L$, which I can understand.

Above the Eq.(2), they says

> One may then proceed to build $SU(2)_L$ invariants by first coupling Φ, $\overline{\Phi}$, H, and $\overline{H}$ pairwise into irreducible representations and finally into $SU(2)_L$ invariants.

I don't understand this.

1. For example, why $(\Phi \Phi)_0$ is gauge invariant? For $(\Phi\overline{\Phi})_0$, I can understand it's gauge invariant, since
   $$
   (\Phi \overline{\Phi})_0=\frac{(-1)^{2 j}}{\sqrt{2 j+1}} \Phi^{\dagger} \Phi \tag{2}
   $$
   where $\Phi^\dagger\Phi$ is gauge invariant. How to understand $(\Phi \Phi)_0$?
2. Why the $\left[(\overline{H} H)_1(\overline{\Phi} \Phi)_1\right]_0$ term is gauge invariant? More specifically, I don't know how the gauge transformation act on this triplet-triplet form. (The expression of $(\Phi \Phi)_0$ and $(\overline{H} H)_1$ are given in Eq.(7-10) in that paper.)

Here I list some equations for convenience.

$$\Phi=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi_{j, j} \\
\phi_{j, j-1} \\
\phi_{j, j-2} \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\phi_{j,-j+1} \\
\phi_{j,-j}
\end{array}\right),\quad \bar{\Phi}=V \Phi^*=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\phi_{j,-j}^* \\
-\phi_{j,-j+1}^* \\
\phi_{j,-j+2}^* \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
\cdot \\
(-1)^{2 j-1} \phi_{j, j-1}^* \\
(-1)^{2 j} \phi_{j, j}^*
\end{array}\right) \tag{A19-20} $$

Comment: Start from illustration (7). How do you tensor-combine two spin 3 objects to get a rotational invariant? Translate this to weak isospin. The 0 subscript means project everything but the singlet (invariant) in the tensor product. So **7** $\otimes$ **7** = **1** $\oplus$ ....   and ignore the ... terms!

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks professor! Your comments is very helpful! May you comment more on why we don’t use $(\Phi \Phi)_1$ or $(HH)_1$ two triplet to form singlet? What’s the key role of the complex conjugation here? Thanks!